# Siar code siarmcmcdirichletv4 plotting does not work properly

Tags: r, plot

I was able to run "siarmcmcdirichletv4" succesfully with these parameters:

```
siarmcmcdirichletv4(data_mat,source_mat,concdep=0,500000,50000),
```

where data_mat is a matrix with 3 colums, fist  with a number for the gender, second and third fpr 15N and 13C values, 119 rows.

source_mat is a matrix with 4 colums and 2 rows, containing Meand15N (v1) SDd15N (v2) Meand13C (v3) SDd13C(v4)

```
    V1  V2  V3  V4
first row:  10.833  1.032   -29.191 0.442
Second row: 11.683  1.143   -22.565 1.568
```

i followed the instrucions on this website: 
https://www.tcd.ie/Zoology/research/research/theoretical/siar/SIAR_For_Ecologists.pdf

Like i said the run was succesfull, but now i tried to plot it with this funktion: 
"siarproportionbygroupplot" but it doesnt work, it just says:"No output found - check that you have run the SIAR model"  I dont know whats wrong because im obviously running SIAR or otherwise the first code had not worked... does anyone know whats wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like your source_mat file has a first column identifying what the sources are. Your source input file should be written something like this:

```
Source    Meand15N SDd15N  Meand13C  SDd13C 
Source_1  10.833   1.032   -29.191   0.442
Source_2  11.683   1.143   -22.565   1.568
```